# How to remove object from array by checking its value?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i remove object from my 2nd array which is $conferance_participants

if this statement is true

if `$participants['calleridnum'] == $conferance_participants['uid']`

```
<?php
$participants = [
    [   'calleridnum' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay' 
    ]
];
$conferance_participants = [
    [   'uid' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'dit' => 'deze'
    ],
    [  'uid' => 2,
        'test' => 'test',
        'dit' => 'wew'
    ]
];

$uniques = array_unique(array_merge($participants,   $conferance_participants));

print_r( $uniques );
?>
```

if this statement is true

if `$participants['calleridnum'] == $conferance_participants['uid']`

i want to remove the object from my second array that has the same value

i want the output to be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 1
            [test] => yay
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
            [test] => test
            [dit] => wew
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($participants as $key=>$p) {
    foreach ($conferance_participants as $key=>$cp) {

        if ($p['calleridnum'] == $cp['uid']) {

          unset($participants[$key]);
        } 

    } 
}
$result = array_merge($conferance_participants, $participants);
```

Or if you don't want to change the $conferance_participants array then do

```
$result = array();
foreach ($conferance_participants as $key => $cp) {
    if ($cp['uid'] != $participants['calleridnum'])
        $result[] = $cp;
}
$result[] = $participants;
```